# How to collect errors using linux

Tags: c++, linux

I made a program with an executable called alltest.o and ran into a fundamental problem.  All test would run another program 10000 times to check for segmentation faults or asserts that I had (this code was to help find bugs for multi-threading).  I ran the code with this command on linux "./alltext.o > outut.txt", but the seg faults and asserts never appeared in output.txt.  When I ran "./alltext.o"  instead of running it into output.txt, I occasionally got errors.  Is there anyway to get the errors to write themselves in output.txt?

Comment: Seems like it would be a lot easier just to use a debugger and step through your program to find where the crash is occurring.

Comment: Redirect stderr as well. `./alltext.o > output.txt 2>&1`

Answer (score 1):

Remember that the redirect in linux redirects stdout to the file.  I would guess in this case that your error is being reported through stderr.  The proper redirect to redirect stderr to the file would be "./alltext.o 2> output.txt".  That would direct only the error messages.

You could also use "./alltext.o &> output.txt" to redirect both stdout and stderr to the file.  There are many combinations you can use.

I suggest reading up more on the redirect.  [Here is a link to a short explanation.](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/redirecting-stderr-to-stdout/)